# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 11 but maven dependency already added

Tags: maven, jaxb, java-11

I am trying to migrate from Java 8 to Java 11, but I'm getting this error:

```
    Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project Core: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
```

Now, I tried to fix this issue adding this dependency to my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I keep getting the exact same issue. I also tried with version 2.3.0.

I looked at my effective POM and the jaxb-api dependency appears there. Also, I opened the jar file that was downloaded by maven just to verify the class is present, it is.

[image: JAXBException class]
Here's my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>Core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Core</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.version>3.8.0</maven.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        ... <!-- Other Sonar settings -->
</properties>


<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mockito testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>0.24.0-RC.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>0.24.0-RC.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-json</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-jcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.10.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.1</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after unit tests have been run -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/coverage/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/web/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- For JPA static metamodel generation -->
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                        </path>

                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- create a complete jar for testing in other environments -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/test-jar-with-dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        ... <!-- some settings -->
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                            <version>${javassist.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                            <version>${liquibase-hibernate5.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                            <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please show your pom file..

Comment: I just added my POM file above.

Comment: Can you run maven with `-X` option? (e.g. `mvn -X clean install`)

Comment: @DevCat So did you find the problem? Because I'm facing the same. `jaxb-api` is here, it appears in the classpath when executing maven with `-X`...

Comment: jaxb was removed from JDK 11. Can be solved using `--add-modules` option. See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/2351996

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same issue, if anyone still stumbling upon this will leave a solution here.

It's `hibernate-jpamodelgen` library that is causing the error.
There is an open issue in hibernate for this [HHH-12991](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12991). You can found a workaround here, didn't work for me.

But `maven-processor-plugin` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61305429/5911964) did the trick

Comment: Thank you man, HHH-12991 now has solution which has worked for me. :applause